# Is Argon2 Quantum safe?

Tags: post-quantum-cryptography

I am developing a post quantum safe GPG like program, is argon2 quantum safe cryptographically for GPG like application.

Comment: Related: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/95257/is-password-hashing-post-quantum-secure

Comment: Does that answer have enough information for you? Because Argon2 is not fundamentally different from other password hashes in this regard.

Comment: Thank you guys , yes the information shared did answer my question .

Answer (score 4):

Simply put, it should be because it's based on BLAKE2b, it's [memory hard](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/95257/is-password-hashing-post-quantum-secure), and symmetric cryptography is relatively unaffected by quantum computing since attacks can't be carried out efficiently compared to those for asymmetric cryptography (e.g. [Grover's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grover%27s_algorithm) vs [Shor's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shor%27s_algorithm)). The [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9106.html#name-security-as-a-hash-function) states the following:

> The collision and preimage resistance levels of Argon2 are equivalent
> to those of the underlying BLAKE2b hash function. To produce a
> collision, 2^(256) inputs are needed. To find a preimage, 2^(512)
> inputs must be tried.
>
> The KDF security is determined by the key length and the size of the
> internal state of hash function H'. To distinguish the output of the
> keyed Argon2 from random, a minimum of (2^(128),2^length(K)) calls to
> BLAKE2b are needed.

That's enough not to worry.

Comment: Grover's Algorithm doesn't preclude existence of another more efficient algorithm in a particular case so the comment about it doesn't make sense.

Comment: @ReinstateMonica How's the wording now?