Do 512 bit hash functions meant for post quantum world?
for instance SHA2-512, İs it overkill to use currently?

The answer by Daniel S says it all - it can't even work theoretically/logically (too little to gain from parallel quantum computing), let alone practically/physically (no QC can scale that big as of 2022).

While Grover's machine is Optimal, there is also a special one for hash functions due to Brassard et. al. Don't miss the memory requirements.

https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/98258/18298
