# Grover's algorithm explained for children?

Tags: quantum-cryptanalysis, grovers-algorithm

Can you explain the mathematical details of Grover's algorithm for children?

Comment: We're not ChatGPT.

Answer (score 3):

This is the crypto stack exchange. And if there is one thing I learned in crypto, you always have to specify everything, especially the power of the participants.

Therefore, because you did not specify the knowledge of the children, I assume all children have graduated in computer science and quantum mechanics. Thus, they will easily understand the following:

1. Initialize the system to the uniform superposition over all states:

$$
|\psi_0\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{N}} \sum_{i=0}^{N-1} |i\rangle,
$$

Obviously $N$ is the search space.

2. Oracle for state $|\psi_0\rangle$ to invert $|w\rangle$:

\begin{equation}
|\psi_1\rangle = U_w |\psi_0\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{N}} \sum_{i=0}^{N-1} (-1)^{f(i)} |i\rangle,
\end{equation}

where $f(i) = 1$ if $i=w$ or $f(i) = 0$

3. Amplify $|w\rangle$ with:
   \begin{equation}
   |\psi_2\rangle = S D |\psi_1\rangle = S \left(2 |\psi_1\rangle \langle \psi_1| - \mathbb{I} \right) |\psi_1\rangle,
   \end{equation}
   with:
   \begin{equation}
   S|i\rangle = (-1)^{i=w}|i\rangle.
   \end{equation}
   and:
   \begin{equation}
   D = 2|\psi_0\rangle\langle\psi_0| - I,
   \end{equation}
4. Iterate over 2. and 3. $O(\sqrt{N})$ times to increase probability. Trivial.
5. Measure quantum state. Everyone knows how that works.

"Yes, it really is that simple"

Edit: I forgot the relation to crypto. Just assume a cryptographic scheme as the black box function to which the Grovers algorithm is applied and brute force the key.

/s

Maybe [this](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/96087/grover-algorithm-for-public-key-cryptography-frodokem) answers your question.

Comment: When explaining a cryptographic thing (e.g. signature) to children, I find it useful to first explain _what_ the thing does (e.g. allow public verification of the authenticity of a message) and under what high level _assumptions_ (e.g. authenticity of a public key, and secrecy of a matching private key known only to signer), without explaining the _how_ (e.g. RSA or ECDSA) at first. The [current answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/revisions/106201/2) does that only in the final _Edit_. IMHO that should be first, and more detailed.